# What do you call someone who does good things for selfish reasons?

Tags: single-word-requests

Like someone who donates to charity not because they actually want to donate, but so that they can feel good about themselves.

Is there one specific word to describe that someone? Or is there just not one accurate word for that?

Comment: Can say **Pseudo** when someone pretending to be good.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean here. If I actually want to donate, why shouldn't I feel good about myself when I do that?

Comment: Single word requests require a sample sentence.

Answer (score 0):

Altruism would be the word for people who put others before them, and donating could be an example, so then egoism is defined as the opposite concept.

Maybe you are looking for the word egotistical or self-interested or disingenuous, if you're looking for an adjective descriptor.

Comment: Welcome to SE EL&U. You explain the meaning of a word that is the opposite to what is asked for, and then make a few suggestions without any justification. Please read the introductory tour to find out what kind of answers are required here. You need to explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.